# Exists any document viewer to installa on my own server?

Tags: download, document, viewer

I'm looking for a document viewer for at least office documents and PDF documents. It must be at least HTML5 based.

I have found Crocodoc, but it has not the OnPremise version available yet. I have also found FlexPaper, but it's only for pdf documents...

Any idea? Do you know any product??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a product that is HTML5 based, Snowbound Software has a viewer that supports office documents and PDF documents and would but on your server.